# Enable Portfolio in Wordpress offline

Tags: wordpress, portfolio

I have problem with Wordpress.
I already read documentation on Wordpress's Web.
Mysite - Settings - Content Type - Portfolio.
But in my dashboard, is not show Content type - Portfolio.
only show like below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr9Mh.png)

Can you help me to solve this case??

Answer (score 0):

Portfolio post types are not part of WordPress core and must be added by a plugin or theme to appear. I believe the Portfolio setting you expect to be there would be added by a plugin called 'Jetpack'.

The question title says 'offline' but the question content doesn't mention that. Assuming that by 'offline' you mean a local installation then to enable Jetpack you may need to forward traffic through your router to the local installation as Jetpack requires an active hookup to wordpress.com to activate and fully enable.